# My Vue CLI build is taking forever and I'm not sure why. Can someone provide guidance?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I'm using the Vue CLI to compile my single page application.  I am using Vue Router, Vuex, Axios and Vuetify as imported libraries.  I have been using `npm run serve` during development and that has been fine, however I now want to compile for production.

I have used the command `npm run build` and the build starts fine with no errors shown, but it seems to never end.  I stopped it after half an hour because I thought that was far too long.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  I assumed it would only take a couple of minutes if that.   I'm sure there is some configuration I am missing.

**UPDATE**
My `vue.config.js` file contents:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    writeToDisk: true,
  },
}
```

When I run `npm run build`, according to package.json this will run `vue-cli-service build`

Comment: Could you post the code he runs on build?

Comment: @Wimanicesir Updated the post with config code.

Comment: The code executed is inside pacakage.json, under scripts